# SIMD optimisation for cross-pattern access

Tags: c++, simd

I'm tryint to write a monte-carlo simulation of the Ising model, and I was wondering if it was possible to use SIMD optimisations for accessing data in a cross pattern.

I basically want to know if there's any way of speeding up this function.

```
//up/down/left/right stencil accumulation
float lattice::compute_point_energy(int row, int col) {
  int accumulator=0;
  accumulator+= get(row? row-1: size_-1, col);
  accumulator+= get((row+1)%size_, col);
  accumulator+= get(row, col? col-1: size_-1);
  accumulator+= get(row, (col+1)%size_) ;
  return -get(row, col) * (accumulator * J_ + H_);
}
```

`get(i, j)` is a method accesses a flat `std::vector` of `short`s. I see that there might be a few problems: the access has lots of ternary logic going on (for periodic boundary conditions), and none of the vector elements are adjacent. Is it to make `SIMD` optimisations for this chunk, or should I keep digging? Re-implementing the adjacency matrix and/or using a different container (e.g. an array, or vector of different type) are an option.

Comment: You could consider running 4 simulations in parallel or something using an interleaved array like `struct { align(16) int elem0, elem1, elem2, elem3; } array[something];`  But that uses 4x the RAM, and only helps if you can combine the results of 4 shorter simulations into 1 big monte-carlo simulation.

Comment: Are you computing this for all cells at the same time? SIMD could help you computing 4 or 8 cells at the same time.

Comment: @PeterCordes, no I need the simulations to be independent. @chtz, apparently it can only help in preloading the two cells that are adjacent in the underlying vector (and as it turns out the compiler already does that with `-O3`). I was more thinking of: how do I rearrange the data to make SIMD possible on all 4.

Comment: chtz is asking if you loop over all rows and cols with this function.  If so, look for optimizations after inlining this into that loop (i.e. compute 4 or 8 results in parallel, instead of trying to speed up the computation of one result with a lot of expensive shuffling.) That would make loading 4 adjacent values from `row-1` and `row+1` useful, for example: you can use a "vertical" add to get `data[row-1][col+0..3] + data[row+1][col+0..3]` in a vector. You'd need some shuffling to deal with the horizontal adds for the middle block, but there's some reuse of partial sums there between results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SIMD is the last thing you'll want to try with this function.

I *think* you're trying to use an up/down/left/right 4-stencil for your computation. If so, your code should have a comment noting this.

You're losing a lot of speed in this function because of the potential for branching at your ternary operators and because modulus is relatively slow.

You'd do well to surround the two-dimensional space you're operating over with a ring of cells set to values appropriate for handling edge effects. This allows you to eliminate checks for edge effects.

For accessing your stencil, I find it often works to use something like the following:

```
const int width  = 10;
const int height = 10;
const int offset[4] = {-1,1,-width,width};
double accumulator=0;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  accumulator += get(current_loc+offset[i]);
```

Notice that the mini-array has precalculated offsets to the neighbouring cells in your domain. A good compiler will likely unroll the foregoing loop.

Once you've done all this, appropriate choice of optimization flags may lead to automatic vectorization.

As it is, the branching and mods in your code are likely preventing auto-vectorization. You can check this by enabling appropriate flags. For Intel Compiler Collection (icc), you'll want:

```
-qopt-report=5 -qopt-report-phase:vec
```

For GCC you'll want (if I recall correctly):

```
-fopt-info-vec -fopt-info-missed
```

Comment: That's a very good idea. The gcc command doesn't work, otherwise answered everything I need.